# SQL server: populating a column based on other table values

Tags: sql

I have two tables:
TableA

```
ID AID  BID   Status
1  100  1000
2  101  1001
3  102  1000
```

and so on...

TableB

```
AID BID
100  1000
101  1008
107  1001
```

Now I want to populate tableA, status with 'FAIL' if:
1.for AID in tableA, its corresponding BID should be equal to same values of tableB
2. If corresponding BID is not same in tableB, make sure it dont exist in tableB means BID is a new value which dont exist in TableB

Example:
TableA, AID = 100 BID = 1000. now this AID = 100 should be looked into tableB; in tableB for AID 100; BID = 1000 so its not a fail.

1. Therefore for AID 100, BID should be either 1000 (from tableB) or any other new value that do not exist in TableB.BID irrespective of AID.

A.AID = 101 BID=1001 but this BID value exist for B.AID = 107 so its a fail.
Expected result:

```
    ID AID  BID   Status
    1  100  1000  NULL
    2  101  1001  FAIL
    3  102  1000  FAIL
```

Thanks

Comment: Which bit are you having trouble with?

Comment: How to make sure that for same AID if A.BID <> B.BID then A.BID do not exist in B.BID

Comment: Reason for the question (and the downvote) is that your last few questions really look like mini work specifications rather than questions. They don't demonstrate any attempt on your part to solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
Update TableA
Set Status =   Case
               When Exists (
                           Select 1
                           From TableB
                           Where TableB.AID = TableA.AID
                               And TableB.BID = TableA.BID
                           ) Then Null
                When Not Exists (
                                Select 1
                                From TableB
                                Where TableB.BID = TableA.BID
                                ) Then Null
                Else 'FAIL'
                End
```

Comment: Not working ~~~ I guess there should be an inner join in the case statement !!  not sure but this seems like not working !

Comment: There is a reference in the inner queries to the outer table. This is called a correlated subquery. What exactly isn't working?

Comment: @Bhupinder Singh - I see the issue. I reversed the logic which should give you the right results.

Comment: It is still not giving me the accurate results.

Comment: @BhupinderSingh - I do notice that I left the # marks in my answer which you would obviously exclude. Using the sample data you provided, I get the results you expected using my revised solution. Is there a data combination not mentioned in your provided sample data which is not returning the results expected?

Comment: @BhupinderSingh - Technically, inner joins in an Update statement are not supported by the ISO standard. They are a product-specific feature and since you did not include a product tag, they shouldn't be included unless you also revise the tags to include the product version you are using. Second, your suggested solution will produce the same result as my revised solution.

Comment: @BhupinderSingh - Your solution has a couple of issues. First, `...Inner Join B On A.AID = B.BID Where A.AID <> B.BID...` will update no rows as you are requiring A.AID to both be equal and not equal to B.BID. Assuming this was supposed to be `...Inner Join B On A.AID = B.AID Where A.BID <> B.BID...`, it still has a hole in the logic...

Comment: @BhupinderSingh - Your solution would only update TableA rows where the TableA.AID value exists in TableB. I.e., it will not update the TableA row where ID = 3 to "FAIL" because AID = 102 does not exist in TableB. From your requirements, I read that either the TableA.AID value exists in TableB and its TableB.BID is different, or the given TableA row's BID value does not exist in TableB regardless of whether the TableA.AID exists in TableB. If the TableA value must exist in TableB, then the row with ID = 3 shouldn't be updated.

Comment: yeah Inner Join B On A.AID = B.AID Where A.BID <> B.BID is right. my bad.

Comment: @BhupinderSingh - So, is it supposed to be the case that only TableA rows with matching AID values in TableB should be updated or not? I.e., should the TableA row with ID=3 be updated or not?

Comment: I am not sure if I can have different AID in tableA. I need to talk with vendor about this. If not, then are we good with my query ? Else we can use yours ? my vendor is pissing me and my company off !!

Answer (score 2):

Just stumbled on this un-answered question while looking at something else. 
These two queries in the same order seems to be a simple answer:

```
  update TableA
    set Status = 'F'

    update TableA T
    Set Status = 'N'
    where T.ID in (Select A.ID from TableA A, TableB B
                                    where A.AID = B.AID and A.BID = B.BID)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using **bigint** as datatype because I simply don't know what king of type is there...
This should help anyway:

```
DECLARE @ID bigint, @BID bigint

DECLARE CURSOR_CHECK CURSOR FOR
SELECT ID, BID FROM tableA

OPEN CURSOR_CHECK
FETCH NEXT FROM CURSOR_CHECK INTO @ID, @BID

BEGIN TRANSACTION

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS == 0
BEGIN

   IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableB WHERE BID = @BID) > 1)
      UPDATE tableA SET status = 'FAIL' WHERE id = @ID

   FETCH NEXT FROM CURSOR_CHECK INTO @ID, @BID

END

COMMIT
```